# Fourier coefficients, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(|a_n|+|b_n|)<\infty$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f$ is absolutely continuous on $[0,2\pi]$ with $f'\in L^2[0,2\pi]$ and $f(0)=f(2\pi)$. I would like to prove
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(|a_n|+|b_n|)<\infty.$$
By using Parseval's identity, I have shown that
$$\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}|f'|^2=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^2(|a_n|^2+|b_n|^2).$$
Does this help? Thanks.

Comment: use $2|a_n| \le n^2|a_n|^2+1/n^2$ and same for $|b_n|$ and you are done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Cauchy-Schwarz,
$$ \sum_n |a_n| \leq \left( \sum_n n^2|a_n|^2 \right)^{1/2} \left( \sum_n \frac{1}{n^2} \right)^{1/2} \leq \|f'\|_{L^2} \left(\sum_n \frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{1/2} < \infty.$$ Do similar estimate for $\sum_n |b_n|$ and the proof is complete.

Comment: Thank you. Can we use this result to infer that the Fourier series of $f$ converges to $f$ uniformly on $[0,2\pi]$?